# Stack trace of the application specific java threads

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, stack-trace

I am aware of tools like stack that gives the stack trace of various threads in the JVM. But it does not differentiate between application specific threads vs others like JVM threads (e.g., gc threads, compiler, vm, vm periodic etc.,). Any flags in the output of this tool to differentiate the thread type.

By application, I am looking for the main thread and any other thread that gets spawned out of it (could be spring or some app dependent 3rd party threads)